# How to log time spent from when script started instead of actual time when using python logging module?

Tags: python, logging

I am looking for a way to change python logging module to display time spent form when the script started instead of current time.

Comment: I updated my answer in response to your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `%(relativeCreated)s` in your format string, as indicated in [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes).

**Update:** You can use normal Python format specifiers to control precision, e.g. `%(relativeCreated).0f` to show floating point values with zero decimal places.

Comment: Really nice option! Only it if would be possible to hide the milliseconds, 4 digits of precission that are not necessary for most cases.

Comment: I would prefer to show only seconds, but still I accept your answer because it's so simple :D

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass `logging.Formatter` and reimplement `formatTime`. Something like that:

```
start_time = datetime.now()

class MyFormatter(logging.Formatter):

    def formatTime(self, record, datefmt=None):
        delta = (datetime.now() - start_time).total_seconds()
        return "{}".format(delta)
```

And then:

```
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
fmt = MyFormatter('%(filename)s %(levelname)-8s [%(asctime)s]  %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(fmt)

log = logging.getLogger('main')
log.addHandler(handler)
log.debug("=)")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this.

Define a custom formatter at the beginning of your script:

```
import time
import logging
import datetime as dt

class MyFormatter(logging.Formatter):

    def __init__(self,fmt=None,datefmt=None):
        super(MyFormatter,self).__init__(fmt,datefmt)
        self.reftime = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(time.localtime()))

    def formatTime(self, record, datefmt=None):
        ctime = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(self.converter(record.created)))
        ct = (ctime - self.reftime).timetuple()
        if datefmt:
            s = time.strftime(datefmt, ct)
        else:
            t = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", ct)
            s = "%s,%03d" % (t, record.msecs)
        return s
```

Then setup your logging system:

```
handler = logging.StreamHandler(MyFormatter())
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

etc...